# gnuplot: plotting with image, how to add a contour

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following scenario: I plot data using `with image` to plot a map of intensity levels. They are already binned. Now I am looking for a way to plot the same data such that I can get a contour plot. I want to this so that I can use this plot as an overlay over another plot so that people see the intensity levels there.

I know it would be possible with using lines, but then I would have to create the lines from data first while identifying the borders of each intensity level. I hope there is a more straight forward way to achieve this with gnuplot.

To visualize what I want to achieve here an example plot using `with image`:

[image: intensity plot]

And for this I would like to get contours like shown [here](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.ch/search?q=contour).

The data is in the following format:

```
0 0 36
0 1 36
0 2 36
0 3 36
0 4 36
```

with each line containing: XCoord YCoord IntensityLevel

What I want to achieve is to have a plot from the same data which gives me contour lines for the intensity level (such that I could also decide to make contours stretch of two or more intensity levels). Is there a way t achieve this without generating new data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using a table to generate the contours with `splot`. Something along these lines:

```
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels auto 20 # Modify this to your liking
# I'm not sure this is actually needed
set view map
unset clabel
#
set table "contours.dat"
splot "data.dat" u 1:2:3 not
unset table
unset contour

plot "data.dat" u 1:2:3 w image not, "contours.dat" u 1:2 lc 0 w l not
```

I put lots of contours (20) so you can see the effects. For contour options, try `help set cntrparam`.

[image]

Another possibility is to use directly `splot ... with pm3d` instead of `plot ... with image`, but this could be undesirable if you use a vector-based terminal because of the file sizes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'm sorry I could only test it now. I get vertical lines and some contours. I don't know what the error is, but I can show you how my data looks like: http://pastebin.com/DtJbE51W

Comment: @Sjoerd2228888 See edit, it was probably that `unset surface` was missing.

Comment: Btw., is there a gnuplot command to delete the temp file "contours.dat" again?

Comment: @Sjoerd2228888 Try a system call `system("rm contours.dat")` after the `plot ...` command.